# SCIP JNI (Java Native Interface) installation on Ubuntu 14.04:

Tags: ubuntu, java-native-interface, scip

I am trying install SCIP on different computers I have. Now trying on a freshly installed Ubuntu 14.04. 
So I got the scip suit from here and `make`ed it. Then I went to `scipoptsuite-3.1.1/scip-3.1.1/interfaces/jni` and followed the instructions in the README:

```
1) doxygen jniinterface.dxy
   - generates xml documentation
2) ./createJniInterface.py xml/*
   - uses the xml documentation and creates JNI interface
3) create softlinks to soplex and scip in "lib" folder:
   mkdir ./lib
   cd lib
   ln -s ../../../../soplex-2.0.0 soplex
   ln -s ../../.. scip
   cd ..
4) make soplex
   - creates shared library of Soplex
   - use options (e.g., ZLIB=false GMP=false) as required
5) make scip
   - creates shared library of SCIP
   - use options (e.g., ZIMPL=false READLINE=false ZLIB=false GMP=false)
     as required
6) make
7) test your installation:
   cd examples/JniKnapsack
   make
   make run
```

Everything is fine until step 6, during which I get the following error. Any idea?

```
daniel-ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Downloads/scipoptsuite-3.1.1/scip-3.1.1/interfaces/jni$ make
make: *** No rule to make target `classes/de/zib/jscip/nativ/jni/JniScip.class', needed by `all'.  Stop.
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to memory limits the steps 1 and 2 don't create the right set of the files and they crash. That's why I don't have the right set of files expected.